# Pass a reference to an instance variable?

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I want a method to set a value for an instance variable but I want to tell it which variable to set the value for each time I call the function.

```
var first: Key!
var second: Key!

func setKey(for selectedKey: Key) {
    let key = // key selected from picker 
    selectedKey = key
}

func someWhereElse() {
    setKey(for: first)
    setKey(for: second)
}
```

Key is a class so it’s a reference type. Am I understanding reference mechanics right or is what I want a reference to the reference? (Some kind of C type pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
func setKey(for reference: inout Key!) {
   let key = // key value you want to set
   reference = key
}
```

Then you can invoke the method as following,

```
setKey(for: &yourKeyValue)
```

If you want to point the reference to class object's instance member

```
setKey(for: &(yourObject.yourVariable) )
```

According to your code, it will be

```
var first: Key!
var second: Key!

func setKey(for selectedKey: inout Key!) {
    let key = // key selected from picker 
    selectedKey = key
} 

func someWhereElse() {
    setKey(for: &first)
    setKey(for: &second)
}
```

Note the `inout` attribute in parameters. This is very much like pointer in C.
In your case, classes are like already pointing to some kind of memory block (`* Key`).
So, what you need is pointer to pointer (`** Key`).
This can be done with `inout Key` or `UnsafeMutablePointer<Key>`. As Swift doesn't encourage usage pointers, `inout Key` should be used for safety.

Note that if you want to point to `Key!`, it should be `inout Key!`.
If for `Key`, it should be `inout Key`.
`Key` and `Key!` are not the same.

If you want to work with Unsafe Swift, here is the code

```
func setKey(for reference: UnsafeMutablePointer<Key!>) {
   let key = // key value you want to set
   reference.pointee = key
}
```

then you can call it the same way as `inout`,

```
setKey(for: &yourValue)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great, and doesn't have any of the workaroundish flavor of the other answers. Exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367603/return-control-to-function-when-modal-viewcontroller-dismissed for my followup problem :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is make variable identifier in Key class.

Set

```
first.identifier = 1
second.identifier = 2
```

Check this value in `setKey` method to identify the instance variable

Second solution is in setKey method, check reference

```
if first === selectedKey {
   // First Instance

} else if second === selectedKey {
   // Second Instance

} else {
   print("the two instances are not identical!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class that contains the instance variable is not a subclass, you can have it inherit `NSObject` so that it contains the `setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey: String)` method. You can then set the value of an instance variable of an instance of said class with a string as the key.

As for your understanding of reference mechanics, you are right that `first` and `second` would be passed by reference. However, if you change the value of `selectedKey`, you are not changing the value of `first` or `second`, you are changing the reference. `selectedKey` holds the reference, so to change the value of the object it references, you must change its properties, for example `selectedKey.value = key`. Changing the value of `selectedKey` itself changes the reference, so the object it is referencing will not be changed.