# Return control to function when modal viewcontroller dismissed

Tags: swift

I need to present a modal VC that sets a property in my presenting VC, and then I need to do something with that value back in the presenting VC. I have to be able to pass pointers to different properties to this function, so that it's reusable. I have the code below (`KeyPickerTableViewController` is the modal VC).

It should work, except not, because the line after `present(picker...` gets executed immediately after the picker is presented.

How do I get my presenting VC to "wait" until the modal VC is dismissed?

```
@objc func fromKeyTapped(_ button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("from tapped")
    setKey(for: &sourceKey, presentingFrom: button)
}

@objc func toKeyTapped(_ button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("from tapped")
    setKey(for: &destKey, presentingFrom: button)
}

fileprivate func setKey(for key: inout Key!, presentingFrom buttonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let picker = KeyPickerTableViewController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = buttonItem
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let delKey = delegatedKey {
        key = delKey
    }
}
```

Comment: where you set this value **delegatedKey** , also if you set **picker.delegate = self** it's supposed that you have a update delegate function inside your VC ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use delegate pattern or closure.

I would do the following
1. I would not use inout pattern, I would first call the popover and then separately update what is needed to be updated
2. In KeyPickerTableViewController define property var actionOnDismiss: (()->())? and setting this action to what we need after initialisation of KeyPickerTableViewController

I could show it in code, but the abstract you've shown is not clear enough to come up with specific amendments. Please refer the illustration below.

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    var key = 0

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = SecondVC()
        vc.action = {
            print(self.key)
            self.key += 1
            print(self.key)
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    var action: (()->())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        onDismiss()
    }

    func onDismiss() {
        action?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, that works great! However, it's making me add `@escaping` to my `setKey` function, which is now `setKey(presentingFrom buttonItem: UIBarButtonItem, with action: (@escaping ()->()))`. I suppose you didn't create a function that took the action in your example, so maybe this is in line with what you'd expect.

Comment: I think that's ok, escaping closure stays in memory until executed, good material about escaping and non escaping closures - https://medium.com/@kumarpramod017/what-do-mean-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-in-swift-d404d721f39d

Answer (score 1):

While presenting VC, add dismissing modal VC action in its completion handler, so that Viewcontroller will be presented after dismissal is completed

```
present(picker, animated: true, completion: { (action) in
   //dismissal action
   if let delKey = delegatedKey {
        key = delKey
   }
})
```

Comment: Isn't the completion handler called once the modal vc appears, not when it disappears?